# How to update a subdocument in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I know the question have been asked many times, but I can't figure out how to update a subdocument in mongo.

Here's my Schema:

```
// Schemas
var ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first: String,
  last: String,
  mobile: String,
  home: String,
  office: String,
  email: String,
  company: String,
  description: String,
  keywords: []
});

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true
  },
  password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
  },
  contacts: [ContactSchema]
});
```

My collection looks like this:

```
db.users.find({}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5500b5b8908520754a8c2420"),
    "email" : "test@random.org",
    "password" :     "$2a$08$iqSTgtW27TLeBSUkqIV1SeyMyXlnbj/qavRWhIKn3O2qfHOybN9uu",
    "__v" : 8,
    "contacts" : [
        {
            "first" : "Jessica",
            "last" : "Vento",
            "_id" : ObjectId("550199b1fe544adf50bc291d"),
            "keywords" : [ ]
        },
        {
            "first" : "Tintin",
            "last" : "Milou",
            "_id" : ObjectId("550199c6fe544adf50bc291e"),
            "keywords" : [ ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Say I want to update subdocument of id 550199c6fe544adf50bc291e by doing:

```
db.users.update({_id: ObjectId("5500b5b8908520754a8c2420"), "contacts._id": ObjectId("550199c6fe544adf50bc291e")}, myNewDocument)
```

with myNewDocument like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550199b1fe544adf50bc291d"), "first" : "test" }
```

It returns an error:

```
db.users.update({_id: ObjectId("5500b5b8908520754a8c2420"), "contacts._id":     ObjectId("550199c6fe544adf50bc291e")}, myNewdocument)
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 16837,
        "errmsg" : "The _id field cannot be changed from {_id:     ObjectId('5500b5b8908520754a8c2420')} to {_id:     ObjectId('550199b1fe544adf50bc291d')}."
    }
})
```

I understand that mongo tries to replace the parent document and not the subdocument, but in the end, I don't know how to update my subdocument.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the [$ operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to update a subdocument in an array

Using `contacts.$` will point mongoDB to update the relevant subdocument.

```
db.users.update({_id: ObjectId("5500b5b8908520754a8c2420"), 
  "contacts._id": ObjectId("550199c6fe544adf50bc291e")}, 
 {"$set":{"contacts.$":myNewDocument}})
```

I am not sure why you are changing the _`id` of the subdocument. That is not advisable.

If you want to change a particular field of the subdocument use the `contacts.$.<field_name>` to update the particular field of the subdocument.

Comment: Unfortunately, it triggers an error `2015-03-12T16:36:05.188+0100 can't have . in field names [contacts.$] at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:155`

Comment: @user1717735 sorry, forgot the $set operator. Check the edit.

Comment: It works, many thanks! I don't change the _`id`, it's the same. I actually use the command programmatically with mongoose. I don't know which fields will change and thus can't go into specificity with `contacts.$.<field_name>`.

Comment: I just realized that I don't have to specify the `_id` again in my object, I misunderstood that point, that's why you had the impression that I was trying to change the `_id`

Comment: does't this solution replace the entire subdocument with new values. I was trying to update one or two field values using the object sent by the user. But it is replacing the subdocument with a new document.