# Add new fields to specific collection element in MongoDB pymongo

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am trying to update existing array element by adding new fields into it.

```
...
{
   "_id": "f08b466a-163b-4d9e-98f5-d900ef0f1a26",
   "firstName": "foo",
   "result": [
      { 
         "_id":"957ee97d-d461-4d6c-8a80-57351bdc29f7",
         "subjectName":"Mathematics",
         "marks": 60
      },
      { 
         "_id":"0591d9a0-fd0f-4876-9bd3-dec4d5ab452e",
         "subjectName":"Science",
         "marks": 70
      },
      { 
         "_id":"21f42104-791b-4522-81ce-f7ae1b30d075",
         "subjectName":"Social science",
         "marks": 50
      }
   ]
},
...
```

Now I want to add new field to science subject called "isFavorite: true"

like,

```
{
   "_id": "f08b466a-163b-4d9e-98f5-d900ef0f1a26",
   "firstName": "foo",
   "result": [
      { 
         "_id":"957ee97d-d461-4d6c-8a80-57351bdc29f7",
         "subjectName":"Mathematics",
         "marks": 60
      },
      { 
         "_id":"0591d9a0-fd0f-4876-9bd3-dec4d5ab452e",
         "subjectName":"Science",
         "marks": 70
         "isFavorite": true   #-----------------New field----------
      },
      { 
         "_id":"21f42104-791b-4522-81ce-f7ae1b30d075",
         "subjectName":"Social science",
         "marks": 50
      }
   ]
},
...
```

---

What I tried so far?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
...

collection = mongoInstance["student"]
student = collection.find_one({"_id": "f08b466a-163b-4d9e-98f5-d900ef0f1a26"})

for result in student["result"]:
    if result["_id"] == "0591d9a0-fd0f-4876-9bd3-dec4d5ab452e":
         result["isFavorite"] = True
         break

collection.update_one({"_id": "f08b466a-163b-4d9e-98f5-d900ef0f1a26"}, {"$set": student })
```

This is working, but I believe there might be simple way to just find student document by it's id and adding new field to array item by item._id.

Looking for some elegant Mongodb query to find and update specific array element.

Comment: I don't mark it as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012328/how-to-update-a-subdocument-in-mongodb only because it asks about pymongo specifically but it's really a matter of connection syntax. The query is exactly the same. The elegant mongo magic is called [positional operator $](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Blex was on the right lines regarding the positional operator; the pymongo syntax is very similar:

```
db.mycollection.update_one({'_id': 'f08b466a-163b-4d9e-98f5-d900ef0f1a26',
                            'result._id': '0591d9a0-fd0f-4876-9bd3-dec4d5ab452e'},
                           {'$set': {'result.$.isFavorite': True}})
```

Full example using the sample data provided:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pprint

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.mycollection.insert_one({
    '_id': 'f08b466a-163b-4d9e-98f5-d900ef0f1a26',
    'firstName': 'foo',
    'result': [
        {
            '_id': '957ee97d-d461-4d6c-8a80-57351bdc29f7',
            'subjectName': 'Mathematics',
            'marks': 60
        },
        {
            '_id': '0591d9a0-fd0f-4876-9bd3-dec4d5ab452e',
            'subjectName': 'Science',
            'marks': 70
        },
        {
            '_id': '21f42104-791b-4522-81ce-f7ae1b30d075',
            'subjectName': 'Social science',
            'marks': 50
        }
    ]
})

db.mycollection.update_one({'_id': 'f08b466a-163b-4d9e-98f5-d900ef0f1a26',
                            'result._id': '0591d9a0-fd0f-4876-9bd3-dec4d5ab452e'},
                           {'$set': {'result.$.isFavorite': True}})

pprint.pprint(list(db.mycollection.find())[0])
```

result:

```
{'_id': 'f08b466a-163b-4d9e-98f5-d900ef0f1a26',
 'firstName': 'foo',
 'result': [{'_id': '957ee97d-d461-4d6c-8a80-57351bdc29f7',
             'marks': 60,
             'subjectName': 'Mathematics'},
            {'_id': '0591d9a0-fd0f-4876-9bd3-dec4d5ab452e',
             'isFavorite': True,
             'marks': 70,
             'subjectName': 'Science'},
            {'_id': '21f42104-791b-4522-81ce-f7ae1b30d075',
             'marks': 50,
             'subjectName': 'Social science'}]}
```